# View with a page using arguments wtih a path using %

Tags: drupal, view, arguments

I've just started using Drupal and I must admit its brilliant. Im still finding my way around it, so this might be a stupdi question, but Id like to know what the best and least perofrmance impacting way to achieve the below.

I have created a view with the "Node: Nid" argument to bascially list certain information about additioanl information about an  artist, his events, albums etc..... The path has been set using the %. The idea being that when a particular artist node is in the node URL it will display all of the other info.

What I would like to do is add a link to the artist page called more info. So when clicked it takes you to that particular view and display all the other information.
I have realised that you cannot create menu items, using % argument.

How you would you guys do this ?

thanks :)

Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can't use wildcards in menus.

However, you can create a fake menu block outside the normal Drupal menu system that contains the menu items you want: just create a view and use the *HTML list* style. Each row in the view will correspond to one of your fake menu's items. When you're finished creating the view, create a block display for that view.

Add the block to a region using *Site Building* -> *Blocks*, and style it to look like your other menus.